# Using Sed to remove part of FASTA file header

Tags: sed

I'm new to Sed and want use it to remove part of  FASTA file header

My headers take the form:

```
CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens
```

and I need them to be:

```
CYTC2889-12|Homo sapiens
```

So far I have (running on macOS):

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/ /|/1;s/ /|/1' Homo_sapiens_aligned.fas
```

which was used to get `CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens`. Initially `|` was replaced with a space. That is, originally the headers looked like:

```
CYTC2889-12 HM036578 Homo sapiens
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sed, you can try with:

`sed 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)|\(.*\)/\1|\3/' Homo_sapiens_aligned.fas`.

If the results is coherent with waht you want, you can add the '-i' option to overwrite the file:

`sed 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)|\(.*\)/\1|\3/' -i.bak Homo_sapiens_aligned.fas`

Meaning:

- `(.*)` is a generic string of any lengh. The `\` is an escape character needed by the parenthesis.
- `\(.*\)|\(.*\)|\(.*\)` is a sequence of three strings separated by `|`
- `\1|\3` means that you want to replace the aboce sequence of strings with a string that contains only the first part and the third part.

Comment: Thanks. But this results in `CYTC2889-12|HM036578|sapiens` instead of `CYTC2889-12|Homo sapiens`. Plus, the second approach above (with the `-i ` flag) prints to screen rather than modifying a file.

Comment: To write to file, I did `sed -i '.bak' 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)|\(.*\)/\1|\3/' Homo_sapiens_aligned.fas`

Comment: My commands work on my Ubuntu 22.04. Which version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: I'm actually running GNU sed through the macOS terminal, not Ubuntu. Apologies. Should have made it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'CYTC2889-12|HM036578|Homo sapiens' \
 | sed -re 's/^([^|]+).[^|]+(.*)/\1\2/'`
```

`-r` - to avoid the immense amount of `\`
`/^...` start at the beginning of the line
`(...)` - to mark the content that we want to keep, two groups
`[^|]` - match all but the `|` character
`+` - at least one character
`.` - skip that `|` in the input
`.*` - all that remains on the line (here)

`\1` - first group
`\2` - second group, which contains the `|` - character before it.